# can you wipe over your feet once with cotton socks?

Tags: wudu

When i make wudu do it have to be “leather” socks like the Hadiths or can i just wipe once over my cotton socks? Jazakallah khair for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Mazhab of Imam Abu Hanifa (A.R.), the following conditions must be met:

1. It stays up for itself on the feet.
2. A person can walk with these socks (alone) to a distance of three miles without the socks being torn.
3. It is so thick that water is not able to seep through the socks to enter the feet.
4. A person is not able to see his feet through the socks.

According to the Mazhab of Imam Malik (A.R.), it states that these socks, (cotton or cloth) must be made with leather inside and outside so that it resembles the leather socks (Khufain) and a person may be able to walk upon them. Only then, it would be permissible to make masah over them.

According to the Mazhab of Imam Shafi (A.R), it states that an allowance would be granted to perform masah over these socks, (cotton or cloth), when the following conditions are met:

1. They must be thick and heavy to the extent that it is not transparent and nothing can penetrate it (like water) and one can walk continuously upon them.
2. The sole of these socks must be made with leather.

According to Imam Ahmad (A.R), he says that the following conditions must be met in order that a person performs masah on these socks:

1. It must be very thick, to the extent that no part of one’s foot becomes visible.
2. It remains firmly gripped onto the feet and a person is able to walk continuously with these socks.

It is the unanimous agreement (Ijmaa of all the Imams of Fiqh) that if the socks are thin and water can seep through and enter into them, masah would not be permissible upon them. (Bada’ius Sana’i)